# Superagent: Parse gzipped response

Tags: javascript, superagent

I'm making a request that looks like the following

```
request
        .post(url)
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .send(data)
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(err, res);
        });
```

The response from the server is compressed however with the response header `content-encoding: deflate` and throws the error

> Error: incorrect header check
> at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {   errno: -3,   code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR',   response: null }

How would I be able to parse a compressed response here?

Answer (score 0):

Superagent can not handle a response encoded with `deflate` (despite `deflate` being added to `accept-encoding` by default)

If I only accept `gzip` responses

```
request
        .post(url)
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .set('accept-encoding', 'gzip')
        .send(data)
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(err, res);
        });
```

Its able to decompress it, of course this only works if your endpoint supports gzip